# Pyspark autoincrement for alternating group of values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-analysis, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a new column in a Spark DataFrame using Pyspark, which represents an autoincrement (or ID) based on groups of alternating boolean values. Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

```
df.show()
+-----+------------+-------------+
|id   |par_id      |is_on        |
+-----+------------+-------------+
|40002|1           |true         |
|40003|2           |true         |
|40004|null        |false        |
|40005|17          |true         |
|40006|2           |true         |
|40007|17          |true         |
|40008|240         |true         |
|40009|1861        |true         |
|40010|1862        |true         |
|40011|2           |true         |
|40012|null        |false        |
|40013|1863        |true         |
|40014|626         |true         |
|40016|208         |true         |
|40017|2           |true         |
|40018|null        |false        |
|40019|2           |true         |
|40020|1863        |true         |
|40021|2           |true         |
|40022|2           |true         |
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

I want to extend this DataFrame with an incremental id called `id2` using the `is_on` attribute. That is, each group of boolean values should get an increasing id. The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
df.show()
+-----+------------+-------------+-----+
|id   |par_id      |is_on        |id2  |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----+
|40002|1           |true         |1    |
|40003|2           |true         |1    |
|40004|null        |false        |2    |
|40005|17          |true         |3    |
|40006|2           |true         |3    |
|40007|17          |true         |3    |
|40008|240         |true         |3    |
|40009|1861        |true         |3    |
|40010|1862        |true         |3    |
|40011|2           |true         |3    |
|40012|null        |false        |4    |
|40013|1863        |true         |5    |
|40014|626         |true         |5    |
|40016|208         |true         |5    |
|40017|2           |true         |5    |
|40018|null        |false        |6    |
|40019|2           |true         |7    |
|40020|1863        |true         |7    |
|40021|2           |true         |7    |
|40022|2           |true         |7    |
+-----+------------+-------------+-----+
```

Do you have any suggestions to do that? How can I write a User Defined Function for this?

Answer (score -2):

```
        #this is python spark testing file

        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col, udf, struct
        from pyspark.sql.functions import *
        from pyspark.sql.types import *

        spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("durga prasad").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","/home/hadoop/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/test_warehouse").getOrCreate()
        df=spark.read.csv("/home/hadoop/stack_test.txt",sep=",",header=True)


        # This is udf 

        count=1  # these variable is changed based on function call
        prStr='' # these variable is changed based on function call
        def test_fun(str):
            global count
            global prStr
            if str=="false":
            count=count + 1
            prStr=str
            return count
            if str=="true" and prStr =='false':
            count=count + 1
            prStr=str
            return count
            elif str=='true':
            count=count
            prStr=str
            return count
        # udf function end


        testUDF = udf(test_fun, StringType())   # register udf 
        df.select("id","par_id","is_on",testUDF('is_on').alias("id2")).show()


        ####output
               +-----+------+-----+---+
                |   id|par_id|is_on|id2|
                +-----+------+-----+---+
                |40002|     1| true|  1|
                |40003|     2| true|  1|
                |40004|  null|false|  2|
                |40005|    17| true|  3|
                |40006|     2| true|  3|
                |40007|    17| true|  3|
                |40008|   240| true|  3|
                |40009|  1861| true|  3|
                |40010|  1862| true|  3|
                |40011|     2| true|  3|
                |40012|  null|false|  4|
                |40013|  1863| true|  5|
                |40014|   626| true|  5|
                |40016|   208| true|  5|
                |40017|     2| true|  5|
                |40018|  null|false|  6|
                |40019|     2| true|  7|
                |40020|  1863| true|  7|
                |40021|     2| true|  7|
                |40022|     2| true|  7|
                +-----+------+-----+---+
```